# Как задать значение по умолчанию для свойства типа Font в PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

Для того, чтобы отобразить свойства и поля моего класса в PropertyGrid, я для них задаю атрибуты PropertyGrid. 
Например :

```
    [
        LocalizedDisplayName("font"),
        LocalizedDescription("fontValueScale"),
        Editor(typeof (MyFontEditor), typeof (UITypeEditor)),
        TypeConverter(typeof (FontTypeConverter)),
        DefaultValue(typeof(Font), "Times New Roman,9,Regular")
    ]
    public Font Font
    {
        get { return _font; }
        set
        {
            _font = value;
            Refresh?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Как задать значение по умолчанию для свойства такого типа? Текущий вариант не работает.

Comment: хм, странно ситуация: если я пишу размер шрифта не как целое, то все норм

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что тип float.